# How would you display a 2D map with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, maps, multidimensional-array

I am using a 2D array to represent a map made up of grid cells (just like a chess board). I would like to know if there is an easy way in Ruby to visually display this with a colormap. Each cell has different values, so colours would be great to display the results. I don't just want to print out the 2D array. No code required, just ideas.

1. Maybe a library I could use?
2. I am assuming this involves opening a new window to display the map? How?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: if you are using jruby, processing gem (a wrapper for java processing library) lets you easily create visualisations of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the processing idea. I installed it. I am not using jruby, do you think it will still work?

Comment: it is a java library, so it won't work without MRI ruby.  It will only work with JRuby.

Comment: Cool. Got it to work by simply following the instructions in [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/wiki/Getting-Started). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually one thing I am having trouble with Ruby-Processing is that I am not sure how to communicate with a Ruby-Processing scripts using another Ruby script. Say I have Ruby1.rb running, generating some data, and i want to update an interface that is running on some Ruby-Processing script, say Ruby2.rb. How do I communicate with Ruby2.rb to update the display/UI/whatever is being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stick with Ruby then [Rmagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) is probably what you need. There is a smaller and compacted version of Rmagick called [Mini Magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick).

If you want to integrate into the web, then perhaps the canvas is the only thing you need.

Comment: Thanks for the Rmagick suggestion.
I installed ImageMagick and RMagick following these isntructions:
[Installation](http://rails.webintellix.com/2010/01/04/how-to-install-rmagick-imagemagick-on-windows/). 
Im trying to get this to work in Aptana Studio 3, but I am getting an error when trying to run the line "require 'RMagick'"
The error is as follows:
`The specified module could not be found.   - c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32/ext/RMagick2.so (LoadError)`

I have checked and the file actually exists in that specific path. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I got it working following these [instructions](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/27). Thanks!
Unfortunately Windows 7 via RMagick does not have a proper way to display images so I have been looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found was [Ruby TK](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm).
It is not a pain to install like RMagick, and its very well documented. It is not as powerful as Ruby-Processing but gets the work done.